# Firebase phone Authenication through otp

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-module

how to solve this error E/FirebaseAuth( 4187): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17010 null

Phone number verification i added android device verification on google console. in testing mode working but not in device.

Comment: Have you added SHA fingerprints in firebase project settings?

Comment: yes SHA-1 and SHA-256 both added